# Share custom text using social share in wordpress based on current language

Tags: wordpress, wpml, socialshare

I have four languages on my website managed using WPML. I need to implement social sharing on my website. I need to share custom text ( different for each language) using this social share. The current page URL along with the custom text is needed to be shared. Any plugin which serves for this purpose or implementing programmatically could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPML string translations to display any text that is translatable. String translation is a tool that will allow you to translate strings in each language based on the language locale the visitor is at. 
From AddThis.com, you can get buttons without any text. 
So a string implemented in your PHP file, and then buttons without any text would do the job. 
You will need to add string in the base language in your php file and then translate that it in the tool itself.

Comment: I need to share the text to fb, twitter, etc. ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE can be used for choosing the current language. But my question is how could I share the text to social media.

Comment: Ohh, In that case, you can use Yoast plugin and it goes well with WPML :)

Comment: Ohh, In that case, you can use Yoast plugin and it goes well with WPML :)

Comment: IN YOAST where I could find options to add custom text for social sharing. I need to share in FB, twitter, Whatsapp and linkedin.